# Junit/Webdriver - Why my browser is launching twice

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver

Hi I am new to Webdriver and Junit. Need this puzzle solved. I did a lot of research but couldnt find the one that could help.

So I declared my driver up top as Static Webdriver fd and then trying to run cases on single class files (also tried multiple class files) but everytime I run the browser launches twice. I can seem to debug this problem please help. Here is my code:

```java
package Wspace;

import java.io.IOException;  
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class Wsinventory {

    static WebDriver fd;

    @Rule
    public static ErrorCollector errCollector = new ErrorCollector();

    @Before
    public void openFirefox() throws IOException 
    {        
        System.out.println("Launching WebSpace 9.0 in FireFox");

        ProfilesIni pr = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile fp = pr.getProfile("ERS_Profile"); //FF profile

        fd = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
        fd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 

        fd.get("http://www.testsite.com");
        fd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        String ffpagetitle = fd.getTitle(); //ffpagetitle means firefox page title
        //System.out.println(pagetitle);
        try{
        Assert.assertEquals("Webspace Login Page", ffpagetitle);
        }catch(Throwable t){
            System.out.println("ERROR ENCOUNTERED");
            errCollector.addError(t);
        }

    }       

    @Test
    public void wsloginTest(){

        fd.findElement(By.name("User ID")).sendKeys("CA");
        fd.findElement(By.name("Password")).sendKeys("SONIKA");
        fd.findElement(By.name("Logon WebSpace")).click();
    }

    @Test
    public void switchtoInventory() throws InterruptedException{

         Thread.sleep(5000);
         fd.switchTo().frame("body"); //Main frame
         fd.switchTo().frame("leftNav"); //Sub frame
         fd.findElement(By.name("Inventory")).click();
         fd.switchTo().defaultContent();
         fd.switchTo().frame("body");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `@Before` method is running before every test.  When you run your second test, it is calling that method again, and throwing away that old instance of FirefoxDriver, and creating a new one (stored in that static instance of driver).

Use `@BeforeClass` instead.

Comment: Thanks MrTi...It worked...One question though if a class has @BeforeClass why junit ask me have a Test method also in the same? It keep giving me initialization error. I want to write my tests in seperate classes.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  Either google the error you are getting, or ask another question :P  Happy Automating.

Comment: Thanks MrTi..you are so nice to take time to answer my question. What I was trying to ask was. I want to write my 'Tests' in seperate class files. So I wrote a base class file in which I defined BaseClass anotation and an instance of Driver (to use in all my Tests). But junit ask me to add a @Test in Base class file. Which I did by providing a blank test method. But when I run my suite this blank test methods runs along with all my other tests. Causing problem. Need to know which approach is better i.e writing tests in seperate class files or all test in one file?

Comment: I don't really use JUnit all that much, but I believe the best way for you to do it is to have multiple test classes extend a single class that instantiates the driver (in a static initialization block) and get rid of the @BeforeClass altogether.

Comment: You have to make the base class *abstract*.